# Getting thumbnail of uploaded image

Tags: images

I want to get a 'smaller' thumbnail of a large image I have uploaded through the built in word-press media up-loader.

I have briefly looked at `get_the_post_thumbnail` but I don't think that is the correct function I want because the images I want to get thumbnails are not 'featured images'

> Gets the Featured Image (formerly called Post Thumbnail) as set in
>   post's or page's edit screen and returns an HTML image element
>   representing a Featured Image, if there is any, otherwise an empty
>   string.

I am sure I saw wp spit out a number of images when I uploaded the last one. How can I access these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you attempting to get the image? That should be the correct function:

```
global $post;
$image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID );
```

It will return an array of all the image sizes for that given image. You can then grab the image size out of the array, or better yet pass in a specific image size to the function to return the correct size:

```
global $post;
$image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID , 'thubmnail' );
```

as you can see we've passed in the 'thumbnail' image size. $image will then return the url to the image size. You can then use it in an image tag, like so:

```
<img src="<?php echo esc_attr( esc_url( $image ) ); ?>" alt="thumbnail image">
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [`wp_get_attachment_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url)

To get the image src, you can use [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)